Why Dirac's spin-$\frac12$ theory proves wrong Kaluza-Klein theory?
I recently saw Sabine's short video that mentions at 10:25-10:55 that Dirac's spin-$\frac12$ theory proves wrong Kaluza-Klein theory unless supersymmetry is amended to the Kaluza-Klein.
Is there a more detailed explanation and canonical answer for why this is so? First, why the original Kaluza-Klein theory fails and secondly why this is fixed with supersymmetry although supersymmetry is not experimentally proven up to today?

If your starting point is a spin-2 field (metric tensor) and nothing else, then Kluza-Klein compactification cannot give rise to spinors like spin-1/2 particles. However, if your starting point is gravity (metric tensor) + fermionic matter fields then it's not an issue. But the fermions do not arise from compactification of the metric tensor. You don't need supersymmetry, which is just addition of fermionic fields with fine-tuned parameters to give more symmetry. Even if you break symmetry-symmetry, you can have fermions after compactification if you start with some before it.

I didn't watch, but it is not rare that she says things that are non-sequitur. If she said literally what you wrote she said SUSY would be necessary in the higher-dimensional theory to have spin 1/2 in the reduced. The point is that if you dimensionally reduce a field of integer spin you will never get particles of half-integer spin. The higher-dimensional theory simply needs to have some half-integer spin particle, and then the dimensionally reduced theory can have particles with spin 1/2 as well. SUSY in the higher-dimensional theory is not necessary for that, it is just sufficient.

Let me exemplify what happens with a simple scenario. Imagine you consider the space $\mathbb{R}^{1,d}$ and you introduce an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R}^{1,d}$ which periodically identifies one of the spatial coordinates. For example, letting $x = (x^0,\dots, x^{d-1},x^d)$ with the first coordinate timelike, one could define
\begin{equation}
    x\sim y \Longleftrightarrow x^d = y^d + 2\pi \ell,
\end{equation}
for some given $\ell$. Quotienting by this equivalence relation you obtain ${\mathbb{R}^{1,d}/\sim} \simeq \mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}\times S^1$.  The point of Kaluza-Klein reduction is now a simple one: imagine you have a field $\Phi(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1,d}$ and that it satisfies the appropriate periodicity condition to descend to a field on the quotient space. This field then often satisfies the wave equation in the higher-dimensional space, and therefore it is an eigenvector of the mass-squared Casimir operator
\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{P}^2 \Phi(x) = -M^2 \Phi(x).
\end{equation}
On the other hand, you could imagine $\Phi(x^0,\dots, x^{d-1},x^d)$ as a field on the $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$ factor, simply by restriction. If you do that you will find that it does not diagonalize the mass Casimir on this lower-dimensional space. If $P^2$ is the mass Casimir on $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$ what happens is that
\begin{equation}
    P^2 \Phi(x) = -\hat{m}^2 \Phi(x),
\end{equation}
where this $\hat{m}^2$ is a differential operator that acts on the $S^1$ coordinate. What Kaluza-Klein reduction does is diagonalize this operator. This is accomplished by an integral transform (in this case simply the one that extracts Fourier coefficients), and this in turn extracts from $\Phi$ a tower of fields $\phi_k$ on the lower-dimensional space with masses $m_k$, which are the eigenvalues of $\hat{m}^2$.
Now imagine $\Phi(x)$ was a vector to begin with. It can always be decomposed into its components tangential to the $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$ plane and normal to it. The question is that while the tangential component transforms as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$, the normal components transform as a scalar. This kind of decomposition extends to more general tensors and is systematized by the decomposition of a representation of a group in terms of irreducible representations.
In fact, a field $\Phi(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1,d}$ is defined to transform in some representation of ${\rm Spin}(1,d)$ (more precisely, it is a section of some associated bundle to the spin frame bundle by a given representation of the spin group, but don’t worry about this now). Integer spin fields transform in representations of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$, while half-integer spin fields transform in representation os ${\rm Spin}(1,d)$ which are not representations of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$ (on the other hand all representations of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$ are representations of ${\rm Spin}(1,d)$, that being the reason that in general we focus on ${\rm Spin}(1,d)$ as it encompasses both cases). Now, the Lorentz group of $\mathbb{R}^{1,d-1}$ can be identified with a canonical subgroup of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$, namely, the one mapping the hyperplane back to itself. So if $\Phi(x)$ transforms in a representation of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$ it also transforms in a representation of ${\rm SO}(1,d-1)$, however, while by definition it transforms in an irreducible representation of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$, the associated representation of ${\rm SO}(1,d-1)$ is not irreducible. But then it can be decomposed into irreducible representations: this is the decomposition of the vector into tangential and normal to the plane, and the more general version for tensors.
The main point is that integer spin fields, once decomposed like that, will always give rise to integer spin fields (a vector gives a scalar and a vector, a two-tensor gives a scalar, a vector and a two-tensor, etc). If you want to obtain half-integer fields on the reduced theory, the above procedure must be carried out starting from a field $\Psi(x)$ of half-integer spin, which lives in a representation of ${\rm Spin}(1,d)$ which is not a representation of ${\rm SO}(1,d)$.
That is all that you need to produce half-integer spins from Kaluza-Klein reduction! You don’t need SUSY in the higher-dimensional theory. Of course, if there is SUSY in the higher-dimensional theory, there will be half-integer spin fields, and then the above argument tells you that you will get such fields in the reduced theory. Therefore SUSY is sufficient, but as I explained it is not necessary. If Sabine said it is necessary, then her claim is non-sequitur by the reasons presented above and should simply be dismissed.

Great canonical answer. Thank You!

Just a minor question though: Nonetheless I guess there might be a misundersting. Witten has shown that Fermions are necessary for stability of the KK vacuum. I did not check the video, but she might be blundering. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321382900074

And it's not bad to take a look at Witten's papers and see his errors as well. Sabine belongs to two minorities, women in theoretical physics and a non-string theorist. Already under too much inequality.

But there's also the possibility that she means a more general thing by SUSY. Pay attention that without SUSY none of the dualities and their implications/usefulness (as of today) holds. That's already much of the interesting part of Superstring, KK etc camp.

@BastamTajik I've just reviewed Witten's 1982 paper. He does not conclude that SUSY is necessary but instead conlcudes to an alternative explanation and that original compacted 5D KK-theory  is just fine under some assumptions made.

@Markoul11 Yes he doesn't concolude so. But he shows fermionic fields are necessary for moduli stabilisation. If one sticks to the same conservative line of no SUSY and only necessary fermionic fields, I don't know how fortunate one could be! In his following paper on SUGRA he confesses reproduction of SM fermion quantum numbers is difficult. That's why he resorts to singular $G_2$ holonomy manifolds later. Even in that case, again the moduli stabilasion becomes a problem in presence of singularity. There doesn't seem to be any hope left there at least in the realm of falsifiability as of now!
